# How to get the primary key of an item in ListView that doesn't shown in ListView in C#?

Tags: c#

How to get the primary key of an item in ListView that doesn't shown in ListView in C#?
the primary key that i talk about is an auto incremented so i didn't show it in list view

Comment: Please add more information to the question: code sample, wpf/winforms...

Comment: show some code,what have you try?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve that field you should add it to your model class, otherwise to retrieve it you'll need to query again your database to obtain it, and that's very unefficient.

Answer (score 0):

What it appears you are referring to (since you are mentioning a ListView), is the index of the listviewitem (disclaimer: hand-written, not tested)

```
var listItem = listView1.SelectedItems[0]; // Get the selected item (insert null check)
var key = listItem.Index; // Get its index
```

The above is for getting an arbitrary ListViewItem's index, if you want to get the select listviewitems index, you could do the following:

```
var key = listView1.SelectedIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
   var primaryKey = ListView1.SelectedValue;
```